# Beamer Template

Tags: beamer, templates

I would like to know is there any beamer template that is being used in this [presentation](http://mathsci.kaist.ac.kr/~sangil/pdf/rwdslide.pdf). If there is no template kindly help me to make one similar to this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is not made with `beamer`.

In my opinion it is made with the `slides` class.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{slides}

\title{\textbf{Approximation algorithm for the Clique-width}}
\author{Sang-il Oum\\
Applied \& Computational Math.\\
Princeton Univ.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it support figures and tikz environments.

Comment: @user1659936 Of course you can use `tikz` environments. It doesn't support floats like `figure` and `table`, but this does not mean that you can not use `\includegraphics` or `tabular`, just to mention some.

Comment: Then is there any way to use figure and table environments. Can you please provide some source so that I can learn from there. Thank you.

Comment: @user1659936 Unfortunately it is an old quite undocumented class, and I'm not really familiar with it. I remember that I used it about 20 years ago for a presentation at the university, but that's all. Run `texdoc slides` from the command line to see the only documentation that comes with it.